# Ceo hobbies and company stock price index in S&P 500

Tags: scientific-method

Where can I obtain data on hobbies of CEOs of S&P 500 companies?

Comment: What did google tell you? Have you actually tried researching anything and what did you find?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about economics.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

https://hbr.org/2018/10/why-ceos-devote-so-much-time-to-their-hobbies
https://www.businessinsider.com/hobbies-successful-people-2017-2

You will have to use Google Scholar for primary research.